# How does event routing mechanism works in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

I am new to web applications.

I was a windows application programmer. When I write a windows application, there is a message loop which passes received windows messages (e.g. WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE, etc.) to handlers.

Some frameworks (e.g. WinForms, WPF, MFC) do not require applications to directly access the message loop, but instead automatically route events such as key presses and mouse clicks to their appropriate handlers.

Now I am working on web applications using ASP.NET. Does there exist a similar event routing mechanism in ASP.NET? How does it work? If a client side user click a button on the web page, how does ASP.NET find the appropriate handler to hande the OnClick event?

Comment: There is no event routing mechanism in ASP.NET. Think about what you're asking. Where does the code run? And, BTW, the net is stateless (or at least, meant to be stateless).

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. What I mean is that if a client side user click a button on the web page, how does ASP.NET find the appropriate handler to hande the OnClick event.

Comment: This is a very, very...very broad question which is basically asking how the web works. I would suggest forgetting how non web based application work and if you are you webforms do some reading about the postback mechanism or if you are using MVC read up on url routing/posting forms etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a part of the page life cycle. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(VS.100).aspx and look at 'Control events' under 'life-cycle events'.